# Why alert popup a few times after a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

On a page there are couple of Add buttons (`li .plus`).

When you click on a Add button and assume `json.success` is false, it will then popup via `$.colorbox` plugin

The popup pull the data from `href:"/Handle/Postcode/?val" + Val`

There is a submit button (`#submitButton`) from the popup, when I click on the submit button, it keep popup alert box a few times, I dont understand why that happen? how to fix it?

```
$("li .plus").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var Val;
    Val = $('#id').val()

        $.getJSON(Address +"/Handle/Add", {
            Val:Val
        }, function(json) {
            if (json.success == "false" && json.error == "NoArea") {
                $.colorbox({
                    width:"450px",
                    transition:"none",
                    opacity:"0.4",
                    href:"/Handle/Postcode/?val" + Val
                });
                $("#submitButton").live('click', function() {
                   var PostCodeArea = $("#deliveryAreaPostcode").val();
                    alert(PostCodeArea);
                    //Why does it popup a few times?
                });

            }

            if (json.success == "true") {
                Backet();
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats an easy one, because you are using the `.live()` function to bind your click handler. If that code gets executed more than one time your binding happens more than one time.

You can either try to track the state of the binding and only apply it if it doesn't exist, or you can call your click function in the html with the `onClick` attr.

Edit: Just to clarify I meant something along the lines of -

**HTML**

```
 <button id='submitButton' onclick="displayAreaCode();">Submit</button>
```

**JS**

```
function displayAreaCode(){
    var PostCodeArea = $("#deliveryAreaPostcode").val();
    alert(PostCodeArea);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide example what do you mean by "try to track the state of the binding and only apply it if it doesn't exist" ? thanks.

Comment: I would recommend that you do the call inline, but if you really don't want to use `OnClick` you can just blindly `$("#submitButton").unbind( "click" )`

Comment: I have found the solutuon to fix this problem:                         onComplete:function() {
                            $("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
                                var PostCodeArea = $("#deliveryAreaPostcode").val();
                                alert(PostCodeArea);
                            });
                        }

Comment: I added some clarity to my answer with an example of using `onClick` inline. There really isn't any point in binding the click with jquery inline.